# Visual field plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a visual field as can be seen in the middle of this [page](https://www.glaucoma.org/treatment/what-is-a-visual-field-test.php). I have the 52 locations which result from a 24-2 visual test: they are set 6 degrees away from each other and 2 degrees off the centre up/ down and right/left. I might be wrong but the numeric data I have start from the top left of the image. Do you have any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Are you saying you want to print a heatmap?

Comment: The thing is I don't really know if it is a heatmap or not. Maybe it's an intensity heatmap, yes.

Comment: https://pythonspot.com/generate-heatmap-in-matplotlib/